# Accessing object data inside a promise

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

So I have a getBlockByHeight method which is as follows.

```
getBlockByHeight(height) {
    let self = this;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try{
            let block = self.chain.filter(p => p.height === height)[0];
            if(block){
                resolve(block);
            } else {
                resolve(null);
            }
        } catch (err) {
        reject(new Error(err));
    }
    });
}
```

I then want to validate my blocks in another method and am trying to do the following.

```
let previousBlock = self.getBlockByHeight(block.height -1);
```

That line returns a promise with my block object in it correctly. If I console.log previousBlock it prints as follows.

```
Promise {
  Block {
    hash: '5535a9bf09a3667a533df8f8a90a6ae8e8dfe1ca9f3d5305df5a1d593d2afcf6',
    height: 1,
    body: 'longHexString',
    time: '1633881202',
    previousBlockHash: '1f018de4cb50fe2fc57b43c1a4972fde53d7e4ab9ca5809784d49e5a57497312'
  }
}
```

My question is how do I access the hash in this previousBlock object.
if I try

```
let preBlockHash = previousBlock.hash
```

I get undefined. I'm not really sure why this is happening so any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: I don't see any reason for `getBlockByHeight` to return a promise, why don't you simply return the `block` ?

Comment: @NirAlfasi thanks but unfortunately it's a necessity for other parts of my project to be asynchronous

Comment: agree with @NirAlfasi, I think you don't need to use promise at all. since your function is asynchronous why don't you put await for `let previousBlock = self.getBlockByHeight(block.height -1);` ?

Comment: @DarraghCahill I can't see how it's necessary to accomplish anything. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @DarraghCahill "*a necessity for other parts of my project to be asynchronous*" - that should not affect your `getBlockByHeight` method in any way. And in your current implementation, it still does its computations synchronously.

Comment: @Bergi I'm doing a project and it's a requirement. Apparently it will be required for further functionality down the line but I do agree it would be easier to just return the block but unfortunately I cannot do.

Comment: @NITHINPB tried to await it too but get a syntax error stating "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function". 
Even if I add async, before getBlockByHeight declaration or inside it before (resolve, and even if the method where I make my call is asynchronous I still get the same error. 
Very frustrating.

Comment: @DarraghCahill Push back on the "requirement", try to get more details on what exactly is supposed to be asynchronous (the function you've shown in your post absolutely doesn't!), and if people insist that `getBlockByHeight` needs to return a promise ask *them* how you are supposed to use it.